# C# Injeccion de dependencias en UnitTestProject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Buenos días. Estoy montando un proyecto de test para probar un webapi (por ahora solo los controllers). Este utiliza Unity para la injección de dependencias.

Para ello, en mi proyecto de test he incluido la librería de Unity 4.0.1 y he realizado los siguientes cambios.

En el app.config he incluido el siguiente bloque.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<unity configSource="Unity.config" />
```

Y he copiado el archivo Unity.config que tengo en el webapi. Este archivo es correcto y valido pues es el mismo que usa el webapi y funciona correctamente.

En la función de inicialización del test hago lo siguiente:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();
```

Cuando lanzo la prueba depurando, la segunda linea me lanza el siguiente error.

```
No se puede abrir el archivo configSource 'Unity.config'.
(C:\Proyecto\UnitTestProject\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject.dll.config line 8)
```

He estado revisando documentación y aparentemente tengo todo bien puesto. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes revisar si el archivo unity.config de tu proyecto está siendo copiado en la ruta: C:\Proyecto\UnitTestProject\bin\Debug\

De no ser así debes verificar en las propiedades del archivo desde visual studio, si la acción al compilar es: copy always.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no recordaba esa opción. La cambie y todo fue bien.